# Integrating rails with mailchimp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailchimp, mandrill

Currently I'm planning to use Mandrill and Mailchimp instead of ActionMailer. I created a template on Mailchimp, but confused what should be the next step? Basically I have two questions:

1. How to send mail on Rails using the template on Mailchimp? In Actionmailer we can just use

   `SomeMailTemplate.deliver()`

   but how should this work in mailchimp if I want to deliver a specific template?
2. How to pass in dynamically generated parameters? I saw Mailchimp has 'merge tag' that could
   handle this but didn't find very clear document about how to pass the parameters and how 
   the email template is going to catch it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to your problem? I am searching for something similar now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at their gems

```
https://github.com/mailchimp
```

They have examples as well

```
https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-ruby-examples
```

Also from their docs 
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#ruby-rails

I have used the merge tag using their api, look at the examples.

Comment: Thanks Archie, I took a look at their document but didn't find a good answer to my question. Mailchimp api seems to be more related to campaign, but what I want is to deliver the mail using their templates. So should I use mandrill? This thread http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23257181-Using-the-Mandrill-Ruby-Gem seems to be closest to my question but didn't find how to use the template and pass the parameters.